# 60 Second Temperature Moving Average by jobId in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (when time is not continuous)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table with columns jobId, temperature data, timestamps and duration in seconds per jobId. See example below:

[image: Example data set]

I am trying to calculate a 60 second moving average by jobId that starts after the first 60 seconds.

Temp sensors are not returning temps every second, so time is not continuous (*there are missing values*). That is why `avg([tempData]) OVER(PARTITION BY [jobId] ORDER BY [timeStamp] ROWS BETWEEN 59 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )` didn't work for me (60 rows might be way more than 60 seconds).

Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT [dataId]
      ,[jobId]
      ,[plantProductCodeId]
      ,[timeStamp]
      ,[Initial Timestamp]
      ,[timeOffsetSeconds]
      ,[tempData]
      ,CASE WHEN [timeOffsetSeconds] > 60
            THEN avg([tempData]) OVER(PARTITION BY [jobId] ORDER BY [timeStamp] ROWS BETWEEN 59 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
            ELSE NULL
            END AS moving_average
```

Instead of averaging by preceding number of rows, I would like to calculate a moving average based on the duration value.
If the current row shows 61st second, then avg would be based on time from 61 through 2, if the next row shows 63rd second - then 63 through 4.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You could take the first timestamp for each group and apply a numbers/tally table (or if you're on SQL 2022, `generate_series`) approach to it to find partition boundaries for the time intervals. From there, join your time series data against these calculated time partitions to figure out which partition each is in. From there, it's group by partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?
Btw, next time, it's nice if you take time to actually generate some code and not a screenshot of sample data.

```sql
-- Setup some testdata
if object_id('tempdb..#t_measures') is not null
    drop table #t_measures

create table #t_measures (
    jobid int, offset int, tempdata float
,   dt datetime
)

insert into #t_measures (
    jobid, offset, tempdata
)
values  (1, 0, 30)
,   (1, 1, 20)
,   (1, 3, 21.3)
,   (1, 10, 17.3)
,   (1, 55, 34.3)
,   (1, 80, 30)

insert into #t_measures (
    jobid, offset, tempdata
)
SELECT  2
,   offset + tempdata, tempdata - 5
FROM    #t_measures

update  t
set dt = dateadd(second, offset, case when jobid = 1 then '20220101' else '20220201' end)
from    #t_measures t

-- Calculate average between current measure and all measures at most 60 seconds back
;with cte as (
    select  jobid, offset
    ,   dateadd(second, -75, dt) AS lowerBoundAbsolute
    ,   DATEADD(second, 15, dt) AS higherBoundAbsolute
    ,   DATEADD(second, -60, dt) AS Bound1
    ,   DATEADD(second, -45, dt) AS Bound2
    ,   DATEADD(second, -15, dt) AS Bound3
    ,   dt
    ,   tempdata
    FROM    #t_measures t
    -- Optionally, add WHERE c.offset >= 60 or whatever you need to disregard 
    )
select c.jobid, c.dt, c.tempdata
,   avg(CASE WHEN m.dt BETWEEN lowerBoundAbsolute AND c.Bound3 THEN m.tempdata END) AS average15Minus
,   avg(CASE WHEN m.dt BETWEEN Bound1 AND c.dt THEN m.tempdata END) AS averageOriginal
,   avg(CASE WHEN m.dt BETWEEN Bound2 AND c.higherBoundAbsolute THEN m.tempdata END) AS average15Plus

from cte c
inner join #t_measures m
    ON  m.jobid = c.jobid
    AND m.dt between c.lowerBoundAbsolute and c.higherBoundAbsolute
--first X number of measures
group by c.jobid, c.dt, c.tempdata
order by 1, 2
```

The idea is simple, you create a column which is current measure date - 60 seconds. Then you join the table itself where date is between this and current date and take average of that range.

EDIT:
Updated query to include two more average values

Comment: Thank you. This works great. 
One more question. I would like to add 2 more averages with different starting points. One would go back 60 seconds from 15 sec above the current row and the other one would go back 60 seconds from 15 sec below the current row. Could that be accomplished by nested CTE's?

Comment: I updated my answer to include two more measures. The new idea is following: Avoid double-dipping the table by including all possible ranges (+- 15 seconds), and then do the filtering inside the AVG by CASE WHEN.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. The logic worked great. Much appreciated.